# Scrollview doesn't display top part of its content without scrolling it down in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have view which contains a scrollView.The scrollview contains buttons,labels and several textfields.To view the top content of the scrollview, I have to scroll it down.Otherwise it shows only the bottom part.How can I show the the top elements of my scrollview without scrolling it down?It is ok to scroll it up to view bottom contents of the scrollview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@harshiYL it would be better if u post some code in order to detect errors.What i suspect is ur scroll views frame and content size.Use the code below:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
 [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 678)];
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help,I'll try it.I am new to iphone app development and also to the stackoverflow.So,Thank u very much for the quick answer. :)

Comment: I got it done by setting the scrollView frame size.Thanks for the great help :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had to pull down the scroll view to view the content at the top, but when released it would "bounce" back up?

The problem for me turned out to be auto-layout. The view I had place within the scroll view was being centred. As a result, with all the changes that occurred during layout, I think the view got pushed up into negative space.

For me, the solution was to change the layout so that the view was anchored to the top of the scroll view instead of the middle.

Answer (score 0):

By default the scrollView shows always the top. Means ContentOffset is 0. Does the orientation change in any time after launching the app, and showing the scrollView? perhaps you can check  your Autosizing settings in the Size Insprector.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help,I'll check it.I am new to iphone app development and also to the stackoverflow.So,Thank u very much for the quick answer. :)

Comment: If we change Autosizing settings in the size inspector then the settings are being applied to all views. This will lead to User interface changes.